# Why is Hibernate doing hours worth of loads at startup?

Tags: hibernate, grails

Running my Grails 2.2.1 application takes almost 3 hours to startup, both with run-app and when deployed as a war.

There is the usual logging, then nothing for a long time, then the usual logging.  So I turned on hibernate show_sql and use_sql_comments to find that hibernate is going crazy with select statements -- almost literally a million of them.

Examples:

> Hibernate: /* load com.sommelier.domain.core.Venue */ select venue0_.id as id12_0_, venue0_.version as version12_0_, venue0_.address1 as address3_12_0_, venue0_.address2 as address4_12_0_, venue0_.address3 as address5_12_0_, ..... (truncated for privacy)
>
> Hibernate: /* criteria query */ select this_.id as id90_0_, this_.version as version90_0_, this_.name as name90_0_, this_.subregion_id as subregion4_90_0_ from subarea this_ order by this_.id asc
>
> Hibernate: /* load one-to-many com.sommelier.domain.changes.ChangeInfo.changeItems */ select changeitem0_.change_info_id as change3_29_1_, changeitem0_.id as id1_, changeitem0_.id as id143_0_, changeitem0_.version as version143_0_, changeitem0_.change_info_id as change3_143_0_, changeitem0_.new_value as new4_143_0_, changeitem0_.old_value as old5_143_0_, changeitem0_.value_name as value6_143_0_ from change_item changeitem0_ where changeitem0_.change_info_id=?
>
> Hibernate: /* load collection com.sommelier.domain.core.VenueThing.inventorySortOrders */ select inventorys0_.inventory_sort_orders as inventory1_44_0_, inventorys0_.inventory_sort_orders_elt as inventory3_0_, inventorys0_.inventory_sort_orders_idx as inventory2_0_ from venue_wine_inventory_sort_orders inventorys0_ where inventorys0_.inventory_sort_orders=?

The application has always started slow, about 15 minutes, which was at least tolerable, but I recently added a large collection property to a domain, and it ballooned to three hours.  So I think this is a problem that isn't related to the latest change -- it just made the symptoms worse.

So why is it doing this?  Is it creating an index?  Or a cache?  Or proxies? Are the select statement actually being performed, or is it just creating them and saving them to be run in the future?

I have tried removing every suspicious plugin to no avail.  There is nothing unusual in any of my domain classes. And all this happens before anything in Bootstrap.groovy is called.  Is there any code that gets run before Bootstrap?

I do not have a hibernate.xml file -- should there be one?

Comment: 1. It may be loading a cache during startup. Check database tables which are queried, maybe they have a lot of data so it takes time to cache them. 2. Add logging to your code. Try to locate where queries are made and how much of them are loaded during startup. 3. You have mentioned that you added new property to a domain (large collection). Is it EAGER or LAZY loaded? What's the FetchType, FetchMode? - loading queries may be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks Justas.  1. Yes, it is definitely loading a cache because my database CPU utilization is at 90%.  And, yes, they have lots of data -- about 50000 rows. 2. I use a lot of logging, but all this happens before the application is running.  My first log in Boostrap.groovy doesn't appear until after the hibernate selects.  3. All fetching is whatever the default is.  I had one domain that declared custom fetching, took it out, and no change.

Comment: Try to remove that large collection property which you added and check application startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Justas for suggesting to add logging to the code.  I updated the log4j settings in Config.groovy to log "all" for "org.hibernate", "org.springframework", and "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins" (not sure which one did the trick), and it became clear that hibernate was working on behalf of "Compass Gps Index".

A little googling later, the culprit was the searchable plugin.

In my prior attempts to find the issue I had removed

```
compile ":searchable:0.6.4"
```

from BuildConfig.groovy, because it made sense that it was a plugin issue, but apparently the plugin was still running somehow.

So I just added the following to Config.groovy:

```
searchable {
bulkIndexOnStartup = false
}
```

Now I launch in 75 seconds.  From 3 hours to 75 seconds!!

Not sure what consequences there will be from removing the index, but now that I know the issue I can play around with it.